# AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'check'

Tags: python, discord.py

```
def user_is_me(ctx):
    return ctx.message.author.id == "310426385090871296"

@FiveStarBot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.check(user_is_me)
async def message(cxt, member: discord.Member, *, text : str):
    print('\n[Лог использования команды !message]')
    print('Отправитель: ', cxt.message.author, ' Получатель: ', member, ' Текст: ', text)
    await FiveStarBot.send_message(member, text)
```

new error. W/o @commands.check(user_is_me) all works

Comment: Please put the error stack trace in the post itself

Comment: Also, post more of the code. It would not be possible to identify the problem with the code here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `pass_context=True` argument to `bot.command` in order to pass the context.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.check(user_is_me)
async def hello(cxt):
   await bot.say('Hello')
```

Comment: i got new error with new command. @FiveStarBot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.check(user_is_me)
async def message(cxt, member: discord.Member, *, text : str):
    print('\n[Лог использования команды !message]')
    print('Отправитель: ', cxt.message.author, ' Получатель: ', member, ' Текст: ', text)
    await FiveStarBot.send_message(member, text) Error: AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'check'

Comment: @RomanMystery do you have a command named `commands`?  Stop reusing names. If you have to, you can name the coroutine `commands_`, and then pass `name="commands"` into `bot.command`

Comment: So many stupid mistakes. Yes, I already had a 'commands' command. Thank you again for helping me out.